# How we need to retrieve the custom headers in the Spring boot controller?

Tags: spring-boot

I'm not looking for the below headers:

```
Host                    localhost:8080
Accept                  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9
Accept-Language         fr,en-gb;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding         gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset          ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive              300
```

Instead am looking for the **custom headers** which I passed in my below cURL command:

```
curl -v -b ./cookie.txt -H “User:username” -d “user=testacct1@youview.com” -X GET http://localhost:9898/signature
```

-- wanted to retrieve the "**-H "User:username**" in my spring boot controller, please let me know how to retrieve this custom header in Spring boot Controller.

Answer (score 2):

In your controller you can use an annotation `@RequestHeader` to get an access to header by name or to have all headers.

Another option is to use `HttpServletRequest`.

```
public void myControllerPoint(@RequestHeader("User") String user,
                              @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers, 
                              HttpServletRequest request) {

    String theUserHeader = headers.get("User"));
    String userFromServletRequest = request.getHeader("User");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But the @RequestHeader will give you the ones I mentioned in my question which are not needed. I need to know how to retrieve the 'custom headers'. Please see one more time my question, thanks.

Comment: Actually the "@RequestHeaders HttpHeaders" would give desired result, I knew of this but the only problem in which I'd wasted 4 hours is due to the cURL command I used which is having bad inverted commas[copied from word doc], resulted the issue, once I corrected thru the keyborad, the cURL gave desired result from the "@RequestHeaders" code. So closing this question as got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For any header, @RequestHeader attribute in the controller will give you the passed header's value.
The only mistake I did was, the cURL command, has bad inverted commas(“ instead of this "), hence when I tried @RequestHeader in my controller, always didn't get the response, once I realised that the cURL command is incorrect, then was able to get the desired result. Anyways thanks.